SSRS reports in Visual Studio 2022: Culture is not supported
I have a SSRS project in Visual Studio 2022, with several reports and also several shared datasets.
When I preview a report which is using the shared data set "Regions" in Visual Studio, I receive the following error:
An error occurred during local report processing.
An error has occurred during report processing.
The execution failed for the shared data set "Regions".
Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: culture 3072 (0x0c00) is an invalid culture identifier.

How can I fix this error and preview my reports?
The following extensions are installed and enabled in Visual Studio:

Microsoft RDLC Report Designer version 17.0.0
Microsoft Reporting Services Projects version 3.0.11

